# On Azure, how do I find the ip address of an app service to create a firewall rule for it on Azure SQL?

Tags: firewall, azure, azure-sql, azure-app-services

I have created an Azure SQL server, setting 'Allow Azure services and resources to access this server' to no. I have a. ASP.Net application running as an App Service and I want to allow it to access a database on the SQL server.

From what I see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1010457/connect-azure-app-service-to-azure-sql-server-db), the app service ip is static (unless deleted and re-created) so it seems like a reasonable solution at the security level required by my data.

How do I find the ip address the app service will be accessing the SQL server with so I can create a firewall rule?

**Update**: I thought I solved it: Under the Networking tab, and after scrolling down, the Outbound Traffic box shows a list of ip addresses. Creating a firewall rule with one of them does indeed allow the app service to connect a db on the server. But this seems temporary as the next day the db is not accessible.

So still looking for answer.

Thanks!